# Need .htaccess rewriterule help on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to turn these URLS:

```
/mysite/site1/offer/

/mysite/site1/offer/?name=tom&email=test@test.com
```

into to this:

```
/mysite/site1/?page=offer

/mysite/site1/?page=offer&name=tom&email=test@test.com
```

Where '/site1/' will be dynamic and so that wordpress ignores '/offer/' and instead passes a url parameter to the custom template.

Can this be done?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule /mysite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /mysite/$1/?pg=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But I know it's missing the bit to capture the other url params but not sure how to write this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using RewriteBase instead of /mysite/

So this is what the new rule looks like:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/?pg=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: query strings are not part of the rewriterule matching. e.g. `/foo/bar/baz?qux=1`, then `/foo/bar/baz` is what rewriterule considers.

Answer (score 1):

In an htaccess file, the leading slash of a request is stripped off before rewrite rules are applied to it, that means you need to get rid of the leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /mysite/$1/?pg=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I just realized that the .htaccess has a RewriteBase in it 


`RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/?pg=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`


This still look right?

Comment: @petron the base has nothing to do with the regex, but where your htaccess file resides has everything to do with the regex. The base is what gets appended to relative URLs in the rule's target. Since you have a leading `/` in the target, the base is completely ignored.

Comment: I can't get this to work on my Wordpress site at all. It works on this {htaccess tester tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) but not on my site.


$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] just returns the original path.